# Adding JavaScript events to an HTML input

Tags: javascript, html

This code isn't working in Firefox but working on IE and Chrome. When I click inside the text box it runs the `focusOut()` and `focusIn()` functions. Is this behavior expected and is the syntax recommended?

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page of Cage</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="mkx-logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function focusIn() {
        alert("focus In!");
      };

      function focusOut() {
        alert("focus OUT!");
      };
    </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <form> 
      Name:<input onfocus="focusIn()" onblur ="focusOut()" type="text" name="name"/> <br/>
      <input type="submit" value ="submit"/>   
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should work on all browsers since everything looks correct to me.

Comment: Does FF give you an error in the console?

Comment: no error at console. Maybe it's logical error it displays focusIn and focusOut functions at the same time.

Comment: Be careful about using alerts from focus event handlers, because the alert itself removes focus from the element.

Comment: This syntax is *so* deprecated... like, this was what you'd do a decade ago. Ever used [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Not really deprecated, don't forget in the new AngularJS you can still do `ng-eventname` ;)

Comment: This syntax isn't deprecated.

Comment: Try logging messages to the console instead using alerts. As @nnnnnn says, alerts gain focus and makes your input loses it, that is why it is firing both events. If you use console.log() instead alert , your input won't trigger blur event.

Comment: Works in my FF (latest, linux).

Comment: "Deprecated" doesn't mean it doesn't work anymore, it means it's not the recommended way of doing things anymore. Behavior should not be defined where only structure should. e.g. don't mix your JavaScript into your HTML. Not to mention `onfocus="focusIn()"` is pretty much `eval`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin#Browser_compatibility, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout#Browser_compatibility _“This event is not yet supported in Firefox, see bug [687787](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687787)”_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `alert` with `console.log` and watch your web browser console using the developer tools. Just like nnnnnn said in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:Why the code is not working?**
A: `onfocus` is fired when focus is gained and `onblur` is fired when focus is lost. In your code when you focus on the textbox it generates `onfocus` and at the same time the `alert box` is generated and it has lost the focus. So, Both the function are launched.

`Check out this Fiddle`